# Creating Travel time for road segements

Tags: qgis, postgis

I would like to calculate travel time by bicycle in postgis. Following this example from the book QGIS becoming a GIS power user, the calculation is in walking distance. How can I calculate if bicycle travel means are used.

```
ALTER TABLE newark_osm ADD COLUMN traveltime_min float8;
UPDATE newark_osm SET traveltime_min = length_m / 6000.0 *
60;
SELECT *
FROM pgr_drivingdistance('SELECT id, source, target,
traveltime_min as cost FROM newark_osm'::text, 1,
100000::double precision, false, false) di (seq, id1,
id2, cost)
JOIN newark_osm rd ON di.id2 = rd.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_performance#Typical_speedsFQjCNHI_s6y3AXfmOr9zAP6JiO5duS2OQ) says the average bike speed is 15.5km/h. 
You would therefore change the update query to

```
UPDATE newark_osm SET traveltime_min = length_m / 15500.0 * 60;
```

(15500m = 15.5km, times 60 minutes in one hour => time in minutes)